# Create a numpy image with constant color

Tags: python, numpy

It's easy to create a color image with a constant scalar across all channels:

```
height, width = 3, 4
shape = (height, width)
num_channels = 3
scalar_value = 0.5
image = np.full((*shape, num_channels), scalar_value)
```

Is there an easy way to create an image with a constant color vector?

```
vector_value = (0.3, 0.4, 0.5)  # e.g. (red, green, blue)
image = create_new(shape, vector_value)
```

This could be done using a custom function:

```
def create_new(shape, vector_value):
  image = np.empty((*shape, len(vector_value)))
  image[...] = vector_value
  return image
```

but I am wondering if this can be done using a simple `numpy` expression.

Comment: That's a pretty simple expression as-is. Perhaps something using [`put_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html#numpy.put_along_axis)?

Comment: `np.full` should really be able to accept any value that's broadcastable.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, generalizing `np.full` would be ideal.

Comment: Wait, apparently it does...

Comment: Apparently, the numpy folks noticed a few days ago as well: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14837

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for [`np.full`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) is a little misleading (read incorrect). It accepts any broadcastable value as `fill_value`, not just a scalar. That means you can just do

```
np.full((*shape, len(vector_value)), vector_value)
```

I tested this with numpy version 1.17.3, and I'm not sure when that changed. My guess is that if you go back far enough, the documentation held true, and `fill_value` could only be a scalar.

There is currently an issue open to update the documentation: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14837 .

Comment: For example, to create a 100x100 3D blue image:
`blue_image = np.full((100, 100, 3), (255, 0, 0), dtype=np.uint8)`

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work, although it creates a view onto the vector rather than a separate image array:

```
image = np.broadcast_to(vector_value, (*shape, num_channels))
```

Perhaps this one, although it is a bit long:

```
image = np.broadcast_to(vector_value, (*shape, num_channels)).copy()
```

Comment: This is clever. Very +1

Comment: Note that this [is faster](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14837#issuecomment-571840864) than the accepted answer on typical image sizes, and that as long as you call `.copy()` the result is identical.