# I have a json file with list of different values. I want to give different ranges of values different color on based on the value. How can I do that?

Tags: python, json

I have values like this in a list

```
"fsr": [148.0, 136.0, 146.0, 138.0, 158.0, 144.0, 142.0, 146.0, 140.0, 156.0, 140.0, 148.0, 154.0, 154.0, 154.0, 142.0, 146.0, 166.0, 154.0, 144.0, 142.0, 138.0, 140.0, 154.0, 146.0, 140.0, 132.0, 144.0, 140.0, 154.0, 162.0, 160.0, 154.0, 144.0, 152.0, 160.0]
```

Now I want to set a range for different values to have different colors. We have 36 values here so let's say I want a 6 * 6 grid of different colors based on the value. The output can be an image. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .. that said, images (well, simple ones) are just grids of values .. [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and NumPy [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942356/) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69783111/) should get you started (EDIT: better NumPy link)

Comment: Do you need a gradient or can it be random colors?

Comment: I can give values say between 140 - 150 red color, 150 - 160 green color. Maximum I will be using 3 colors only

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you said you wanted at most 3 colors, where each range of values would be the same one. So we may use statistics to group numbers according to which quantile they belong to:

```py
import statistics

fsr = [148.0, 136.0, 146.0, 138.0, 158.0, 144.0, 142.0, 146.0, 140.0, 156.0, 140.0, 148.0, 154.0, 154.0, 154.0, 142.0, 146.0, 166.0, 154.0, 144.0, 142.0, 138.0, 140.0, 154.0, 146.0, 140.0, 132.0, 144.0, 140.0, 154.0, 162.0, 160.0, 154.0, 144.0, 152.0, 160.0]
_min = min(fsr)
_max = max(fsr)
diff = _max-_min
quantiles = statistics.quantiles(fsr, n=3)
print(quantiles)
```

We get 2 quantiles, `[142.66666666666666, 154.0]`, so we can assign a color for each group:

- values below q0
- values between q0 and q1
- values above q1

```py
colors = [
    [255,0,0],
    [0,255,0],
    [0,0,255]
]

# this can be refactored to accomodate different dimensions
def transform_into_color(x):
    if x <= quantiles[0]:
        return colors[0]
    if x <= quantiles[1]:
        return colors[1]
    else:
        return colors[2]

transformed = [transform_into_color(x) for x in fsr]
print(transformed)
```

Which outputs:

```
[[0, 255, 0], [255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [255, 0, 0], [0, 0, 255], [0, 255, 0], [255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [255, 0, 0], [0, 0, 255], [255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255], [0, 0, 255], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255]]
```

Now we can do some matrix manipulation and generate a picture using numpy and matploblib:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# reshape into a matrix
array = np.array(transformed, dtype=int)
matrix = array.reshape((6,6,3))
print(matrix)


plt.imshow(matrix)
plt.show()
```

Which shows the following image:

[image: rgb matrix]